# What types services count as intermediary consumption when calculating GDP?

Tags: gdp, services

What types of services count as intermediary consumption when calculating GDP? I'm not quite sure where the line is drawn. The examples below try to illustrate my confusion.

Say a supermarket provider licenses a piece of logistics software to use when routing its goods to each of its stores. That feels like it is intermediate consumption as the software is being used to deliver goods to people for consumption and therefore shouldn't be included in GDP but will be reflected in the final price the consumer pays. However, licensing the logistics software creates new capital as they will now be able to use the software and they weren't able to before. This sounds like investment. Therefore, if it is counted as investment, then it should contribute to GDP. If it is the case that licensing the software counts as investment, if the supermarket provider has to relicense the software for use every year does that mean that it is counted as investment every year?

Another example would be a FinTech company providing fraud detection software for a bank. It sounds wrong that the FinTech company wouldn't directly contribute to GDP even though its software is simply being used by banks to provide better services for their customers and therefore should just be reflected in the prices and terms of services for the bank's customers.

Thanks for any help in advance :)